# how would i stop the movement of an element after a previous element is removed?

Tags: html, css, position

I have these 3 divs here, one of which when clicked becomes hidden, but the third div is removed, how would i make sure that the third div stays in the same position, without using `position: absolute;` and allowing it to be moved by other means (in my case being the moving of a div wrapped around these divs)

```js
$("#sneaky").click(function(){
 $("#sneaky").hide()
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sneaky {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <div></div>
    <div id ="sneaky"></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Instead of hide(), set "visitbility" property to "hidden" on the div after click, that way it's still in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use visibility: hidden for the CSS instead of hide.

```
$("#sneaky").click(function(){
    $("#sneaky").css('visibility','hidden');
})
```